# How to search on a @connection with AWS Amplify

Tags: graphql, schema, aws-amplify

So I have 3 collections in my schema

```
type User @model(subscriptions: null)  {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  email: String
  events: [EventUser] @connection(keyName: "byUser", fields: ["id"])
}
```

```
type Event @model
  @key(name: "byApiKey", fields: ["apiKey"])
  @key(name: "byOrganization", fields: ["organizationID"], queryField: "eventByOrganization")
  {
  id: ID!
  apiKey: ID!
  title: String
  participants: [EventUser] @connection(keyName: "byEvent", fields: ["id"])
}
```

```
type EventUser @model
  @key(name: "byUser", fields: ["userID"], queryField: "eventByUser")
  @key(name: "byEvent", fields: ["eventID"], queryField: "userByEvent")    {
  id: ID!
  userID: ID!
  eventID: ID!
  user: User! @connection(fields: ["userID"])
  event: Event! @connection(fields: ["eventID"])
}
```

And I am trying to search the `EventUser` collection by `eventID` and `user.name`. Is there some piece of amplify that can enable me search by the `user.name` and return the `EventUser` collection?